# MySQL and phpmyadmin are giving me errors

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, ubuntu-16.04, phpmyadmin

I was following instructions all over the internet and when I configured both MySQL and *phpMyAdmin*. *phpMyAdmin* gave me some errors and when I try to connect to *mywebsite.com/phpmyadmin* I get these two errors

> #2002 - No such file or directory
> The server is not responding (or the local server's socket is not correctly configured).

and

> Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed.

Comment: which webserver you did you using for? what does following show service mysql status; service phpmyadmin status; lsb_release -da;

Comment: I am using Apache2

The first one shows 
http://prntscr.com/h0jikv

Second shows
http://prntscr.com/h0jixy

and third
http://prntscr.com/h0jj5v

Comment: ok: `service phpmyadmin` was my mist take ive wrote an service settings for me.

- did you use php5 oder php7?

Comment: i am using php 7

Comment: ok.
Did you have check php7 for example with an phpinfo.php file;

`ls /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/`; `ls /etc/apache2/sites-available/`;

did you restart your apache server after install phpmyadmin (apt install phpmyadmin)

Comment: @DaveM 
Without enough information, no real answers can be given. So ask for clarification in the comment and not as an answer.

Comment: best step you follow this tutorial (basics): https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-phpmyadmin-on-ubuntu-14-04 hopply it is ok to post this link

Comment: What value (if any) have you in the phpMyAdmin configuration file `config.inc.php` for $cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'], $cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket'], and $cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] ? Which phpMyAdmin version are you using? Can you connect from the command line client?